# How to add warning text before object array while exporting to excel in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, export-to-excel, sheetjs

I have an array of objects coming from api, before I print it to excel, I want to merge multiple cells at the top of the sheet, and insert a warning message into them. [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDuqf.png)

I wanted to write something like the following code. But it didn't work. Is it possible to do that with XLSX?

```
this.excelData.unshift("warning message");
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet((this.excelData as any));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
// Put warning message in A1
// aoa stands for 'array of arrays'
const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([['WARNING']]);

// Merge A1 to L2
// Property names: s: start, e: end, c: column, r: row
ws['!merges'] = [{s: {c: 0, r: 0}, e: {c: 11, r: 1}}];

// Append data starting at A3
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, this.excelData, {origin: 'A3'});
```